# Using time and using input as object in a function

Tags: python, function

I started learning Python a couple of weeks ago by trying to write functional little scripts. Here is my latest attempt that tries to inform people of a train schedule.

```
input ("At what time will you be at the  Gautrain station? (example: 09.00): ")
departure_time = input

def Gautrain(departure_time): 
    expected_arrival_time1 = 09.00
    expected_arrival_time2 = 12.00
    expected_arrival_time3 = 16.00
    expected_arrival_time4 = 21.00

    slot1 = int(abs(expected_arrival_time1 - departure_time)*60)
    slot2 = int(abs(expected_arrival_time2 - departure_time)*60)
    slot3 = int(abs(expected_arrival_time3 - departure_time)*60)
    slot4 = int(abs(expected_arrival_time4 - departure_time)*60)


    if departure_time < expected_arrival_time1:
        return "The next available Gautrain will arrive in " + str(slot1) + " minutes"


    if departure_time < expected_arrival_time2 \
        and departure_time > expected_arrival_time1:
        return "The next available Gautrain will arrive in " + str(slot2) + " minutes"


    if departure_time < expected_arrival_time3 \
        and departure_time > expected_arrival_time2:
        return "The next available Gautrain will arrive in " + str(slot3) + " minutes"


    if departure_time < expected_arrival_time4 \
        and departure_time > expected_arrival_time3:
        return "The next available Gautrein will arrive in " + str(slot4) + " minutes"


    if departure_time > expected_arrival_time4: 
        return "Hahahaha. You missed all the trains you idiot!"


    if departure_time == expected_arrival_time1 or (expected_arrival_time2) or (expected_arrival_time3) or (expected_arrival_time4):
        return "The Gautrain literally just arrived! Run, Forest, Run!!"
```

The problem is this:

1. How do I get the input to be used as the variable departure_time in the actual function? I'm  pretty sure I'm doing it wrong even though it kinda makes logical sense (to me at least).

   ```
   input ("bla bla bla")
   departure_time = input
   ```

   (Why doesn't this work?)
2. How do you use time in this context. When someone enters an actual integer it's easy: 12.00 (departure_time) - 10.00 (expected_arrival_time) = 2.00 * 60 = 120 minutes.

   But when someone enters a float all hell breaks loose: 11.30 (departure_time) - 12.00 (expected_arrival_time) = 41?! Where does this come from?

   ```
   >>> Gautrain (11.30)
   The next available Gautrein will arrive in 41 minutes
   ```

This is obviously incorrect as the next train arrives at 12.00 which is 30 minutes. My system will cause people to miss the train lol!

Comment: You are assigning to `departure_time` the `input` _function_! Try `departure_time = input("At what time...")` instead.

Comment: A minor point, when using 24 hour time, typically there is no separator between the hour and the minute, so 1320 not 13.20. Keep in mind that numbers that start with 0 are actually hexadecimal. You might be scratching your head why 012 + 011 is giving you 19 and not 23.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Nice catch! But I think you meant "octal" not "hexadecimal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1 I would use the following code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    departure_time = raw_input('At what time will you be at the Gautrain station? (exameple: 09.00): ')
    print Gautrain(departure_time)
```

At the end of the script so when you execute it it will first call the input and then the function.

For #2 I would use **datetime** to get the difference between the two dates and it would also help you validate if the date format is properly. Here's my approach:

```
import datetime

def Gautrain(departure_time):

    try:
        departure_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(departure_time, '%H.%M')
    except ValueError:
        return "Input error"

    expected_arrival_time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('09.00', '%H.%M')
    expected_arrival_time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('12.00', '%H.%M')
    expected_arrival_time3 = datetime.datetime.strptime('16.00', '%H.%M')
    expected_arrival_time4 = datetime.datetime.strptime('21.00', '%H.%M')

    if departure_time < expected_arrival_time1:
        slot = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(expected_arrival_time1 - departure_time), '%H:%M:%S')
        if slot.hour != 0:
            if slot.hour > 1:
                slot = slot.strftime('%H hours %M minutes')
            else:
                slot = slot.strftime('%H hour %M minutes')
        else:
            slot = slot.strftime('%M minutes')
        return "The next available Gautrain will arrive in " + str(slot)


    if departure_time < expected_arrival_time2 \
        and departure_time > expected_arrival_time1:
        slot = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(expected_arrival_time2 - departure_time), '%H:%M:%S')
        if slot.hour != 0:
            if slot.hour > 1:
                slot = slot.strftime('%H hours %M minutes')
            else:
                slot = slot.strftime('%H hour %M minutes')
        else:
            slot = slot.strftime('%M minutes')
        return "The next available Gautrain will arrive in " + str(slot)


    if departure_time < expected_arrival_time3 \
        and departure_time > expected_arrival_time2:
        slot = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(expected_arrival_time3 - departure_time), '%H:%M:%S')
        if slot.hour != 0:
            if slot.hour > 1:
                slot = slot.strftime('%H hours %M minutes')
            else:
                slot = slot.strftime('%H hour %M minutes')
        else:
            slot = slot.strftime('%M minutes')
        return "The next available Gautrain will arrive in " + str(slot)


    if departure_time < expected_arrival_time4 \
        and departure_time > expected_arrival_time3:
        slot = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(expected_arrival_time4 - departure_time), '%H:%M:%S')
        if slot.hour != 0:
            if slot.hour > 1:
                slot = slot.strftime('%H hours %M minutes')
            else:
                slot = slot.strftime('%H hour %M minutes')
        else:
            slot = slot.strftime('%M minutes')
        return "The next available Gautrein will arrive in " + str(slot)


    if departure_time > expected_arrival_time4: 
        return "Hahahaha. You missed all the trains you idiot!"


    if departure_time == expected_arrival_time1 or (expected_arrival_time2) or (expected_arrival_time3) or (expected_arrival_time4):
        return "The Gautrain literally just arrived! Run, Forest, Run!!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    departure_time = raw_input('At what time will you be at the Gautrain station? (exameple: 09.00): ')
    print Gautrain(departure_time)
```

And here's how it would work:

```
$ python train.py
At what time will you be at the Gautrain station? (exameple: 09.00): 10.20
The next available Gautrain will arrive in 01 hour 40 minutes
$ python train.py
At what time will you be at the Gautrain station? (exameple: 09.00): 09.00
The Gautrain literally just arrived! Run, Forest, Run!!
$ python train.py
At what time will you be at the Gautrain station? (exameple: 09.00): 22.00
Hahahaha. You missed all the trains you idiot!
```

You can even improve the code by doing an extra function that calculates the difference between both dates:

```
def calculate_diff_date(arrival, departure):
    diff = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(arrival - departure), '%H:%M:%S')
    if diff.hour != 0:
        if diff.hour > 1:
            diff = diff.strftime('%H hours %M minutes')
        else:
            diff = diff.strftime('%H hour %M minutes')
    else:
        diff = diff.strftime('%M minutes')

    return diff
```

To have the following:

import datetime

```
def Gautrain(departure_time):

    try:
        departure_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(departure_time, '%H.%M')
    except ValueError:
        return "Input error"

    expected_arrival_time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('09.00', '%H.%M')
    expected_arrival_time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('12.00', '%H.%M')
    expected_arrival_time3 = datetime.datetime.strptime('16.00', '%H.%M')
    expected_arrival_time4 = datetime.datetime.strptime('21.00', '%H.%M')

    if departure_time < expected_arrival_time1:
        slot = calculate_diff_date(expected_arrival_time1, departure_time)
        return "The next available Gautrain will arrive in " + str(slot)


    if departure_time < expected_arrival_time2 \
        and departure_time > expected_arrival_time1:
        slot = calculate_diff_date(expected_arrival_time2, departure_time)
        return "The next available Gautrain will arrive in " + str(slot)


    if departure_time < expected_arrival_time3 \
        and departure_time > expected_arrival_time2:
        slot = calculate_diff_date(expected_arrival_time3, departure_time)
        return "The next available Gautrain will arrive in " + str(slot)


    if departure_time < expected_arrival_time4 \
        and departure_time > expected_arrival_time3:
        slot = calculate_diff_date(expected_arrival_time4, departure_time)
        return "The next available Gautrein will arrive in " + str(slot)


    if departure_time > expected_arrival_time4: 
        return "Hahahaha. You missed all the trains you idiot!"


    if departure_time == expected_arrival_time1 or (expected_arrival_time2) or (expected_arrival_time3) or (expected_arrival_time4):
        return "The Gautrain literally just arrived! Run, Forest, Run!!"

def calculate_diff_date(arrival, departure):
    diff = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(arrival - departure), '%H:%M:%S')
    if diff.hour != 0:
        if diff.hour > 1:
            diff = diff.strftime('%H hours %M minutes')
        else:
            diff = diff.strftime('%H hour %M minutes')
    else:
        diff = diff.strftime('%M minutes')

    return diff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    departure_time = raw_input('At what time will you be at the Gautrain station? (exameple: 09.00): ')
    print Gautrain(departure_time)
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error at the: 'print Gautrain (departure_time)'

Comment: @Rooirokbokkie I just tested the code myself and I don't get any syntax error. The code can't have the parenthesis separated from the function name, so instead of **Gautrain (departure_time)** it should be **Gautrain(departure_time)**.

Answer (score 0):

For #1 you must do as @tobias_k has mentioned in setting departure_time = input("At what time...) other wise you are dumping the input("bla bla bla") into nothing.

For #2 you are treating time as a float which is not appropriate.  If you treat time as a float it is the equivalent of saying there are 100 minutes in an hour which obviously is not true